# Why do some insects constantly move their abdomens?

Tags: entomology, anatomy

Why do some insects, such as wasps, constantly move their abdomens?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Insect respiration is passive, with sclerotized tracheal tubes taking oxygen directly to the tissues, and moving carbon dioxide out. By pulsating the abdomen, the movement of gases through this system is accelerated. Wasps, as in your example, are relatively active metabolically, so it is not a surprise that they tend to use this strategy.